# Arduino - Weird behavior reading speaker level input

Tags: arduino, input

I'm trying to detect when speaker starts playing audio, my speaker is connected with a 10uF 50v in series with the positive (red) cable coming out of my receiver, and negative to ground.

Speaker (+) ----- || ----- A0
Speaker (-) -------------- GND

I was reading values from around 200 I believe. I had something like input > 210 and it worked(to detect audio). Now at some point and I'm sorry to say I have no clue what changed the reading changed to 100, it looked weird but at that moment I didn't care much and changed my control value to 110.

Now this happened again and I'm reading 36. I'm kinda worried now I'm doing something horribly wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont think the Arduino likes neg voltages .It might latch up or give false readings.Do something about this .

Comment: Something like what? xD, I'm noob with electronics =/

Comment: Maybe a diode ,could be shottky ,you could use two diodes in a half wave voltage doubler.

Comment: I have a couple of 1N4007, can I use those?

Comment: Yes you can ,but remember the breakover volts of the diode .It wouldnt detect very quiet sounds which may or maynot be a good thing .If your radio is low power then the answer from jasen will work and i think you should try it .If its a high power thing then limit the input whatever you do .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of charge on the capacitor will change the  value you see on the ADC.

change the circuit to this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTSdcg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'll give it a try asap, I don't have 10k ohm at hand, gonna try to get a couple tomorrow.

Comment: You can use other values as long as they are the same. Anything larger will do.

Comment: what! no 10K resistors? in a survey I did of all the junk electronics that came my way in the 1980s I determiend 10K to be the most common resistor in the world! :)  but yeah, as Robert says the values arent very critical as long as they match, and the capacitor can be the 10uF you already have.

Comment: @Jasen : you obviously haven't worked anywhere 11k was insanely popular ... because nobody bothered to refill the 10k drawer!

Comment: I have a ton of 220ohm... hahahaha

Comment: @Jasen So... I found some 80k resistors, and used two 1N4007 diodes. Will [this](http://www.digikey.com/schemeit/#276d) work?. I noticed (linked circuit without connecting speaker cable) that I'm reading 36 from A0, 15 from A1, 514 from A5. Is that normal?